# MaterialSkin Winforms tabcontrol problems

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using windows forms with MaterialSkin reference
when I try to remove tab by:

```
postavkeTab.BaseTabControl.TabPages.Remove(tabPage11);

postavkeTab == MaterialSkin.Controls.MaterialTabSelector
```

and is bound to "mtcMain" as MaterialSkin.Controls.MaterialTabControl
[image: properties of Tab Selector]

I get error

[image: error in form where I show main (Home) form]

Comment: You should edit your post to add the relevant content and remove the links. Links expire. When that happens, your question will have no value to other users experiencing a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i&lt;postavkeTab.BaseTabControl.TabPages.Count;i++){
    postavkeTab.BaseTabControl.TabPages[i].TabIndex = i;
}
```

Add this code after you remove TabPage